# Nginx: Local site loads for a while, then aborts with "server not found"

Tags: nginx, server

i just installed nginx on my machine and wanted to test it with a very simple index.html. However, the site loads for a few seconds, then it aborts with "Server not found".
This is my nginx.conf:

```
user http;
worker_processes auto;
worker_cpu_affinity auto;

events {
multi_accept on;
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
charset utf-8;
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
server_tokens off;
log_not_found off;
types_hash_max_size 4096;
client_max_body_size 16M;

# MIME
include mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

# logging
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

# load configs
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name test.local;
    root /home/marvw/Programme/Privat/Test;
    location / {
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
  }

 }
```

Whats rather weird is that both the error and the access log is straight up emtpy. I triple-checked the URL, it definetly is correct. Nginx is running without any errors, this is my systemd status output:

```
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-12-21 00:45:40 +01; 7min ago
  Process: 2171 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2172 (nginx)
    Tasks: 9 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 7.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─2172 nginx: master process /usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr;
           ├─2173 nginx: worker process
           ├─2174 nginx: worker process
           ├─2175 nginx: worker process
           ├─2176 nginx: worker process
           ├─2177 nginx: worker process
           ├─2178 nginx: worker process
           ├─2179 nginx: worker process
           └─2180 nginx: worker process

Dez 21 00:45:40 <<personal information>> systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Dez 21 00:45:40  <<personal information>> systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `test.local` to your hosts or changing it to `localhost`.  "Server not found" is not an Nginx problem.

Comment: No, I didn't. How do I do that?

Comment: Depend on the OS on your machine. On unix (Linux, macOS) generally you can edit `/etc/hosts` with administrative rights (sudo).